# Regexp to match everything before certain characters in php

Tags: php, regex

I need the regex expression to match everything from beginning till I encounter one of these characters ; or [ or { or ( In case these characters are not there then the whole word needs to be matched..

I am using `preg_match("/(.*?)(?=(;|\[|\(|{|))/", $word , $val);`

The first group should be there as I need the matched value in $val. This is php. Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match("/^([^[{(;]*)/", $word , $val);`

Comment: You're sure it works without escapes? Don't think so right now unless there's special handling till `[` encounters a `]`.

Comment: @Mario — Most characters lose their special meaning in character classes.

Comment: Yes, the rules are different inside `[]` character classes.

Comment: @Ben Blank: Oops, thanks. On my screen the linebreak is after the semicolon, so I missed it when reading the question.

Comment: +1 Yup, this is the one you want. The match will be in `$val[1]` (and `$val[0]`). You can even eliminate the capturing parens and use the value in `$val[0]`.

Comment: tried but i dont get any value when i print $val :(  this is the code :preg_match("/^([^[{(;]*)/",$meaning[3],$result); echo $result[1];

Answer (score 0):

`"/(.*?)[;\\[\\{\\($]/"` should do the trick and be a lot easier. Note that you'll have to escape characters that have special meanings in regular expressions. `$` matches the end of the line/string (depending on parameters).

Edit:
Think Anomie's solution might even be a tid bit faster due to only matching one sub expression.